# How to rotate ylabel of pairplot in searborn?

Tags: seaborn

Hi I am using **pairplot** of **seaborn**. How to rotate the y axis title ?

Here is my code:

```
g=sns.pairplot(df,x_vars=x_vars,y_vars=y_vars,diag_kind='kde',hue='Area')
plt.yticks(rotation=45)
```

The above code doesn't work.  I also tried `g.set_ylabels(rotation=45)` but the error told me there is no attribute of `set_ylabels` or `set_yticklabels`. I googled a lot and I didn't find the answer. So please help me. Thanks.

Comment: the previous answer didn't work for me. I am trying to rotate y axis title instead of y axis tick label. Thanks